Truncate off-diagonal values of PSD matrices results in PSD?
Suppose I have a PSD matrix $X$ with 1 on the diagonal and all off-diagonal values with magnitudes less than or equal to 1. Suppose I truncate some of the off-diagonal values by some small $\epsilon$ (meaning that we change the magnitude of some $x_{ij}$) while keeping the matrix symmetric. Can we say anything about the truncated matrix being PSD with some assumptions made on $\epsilon$ or $X$? If so, what can we say, and what assumptions will we need to make?

The matrix $\pmatrix{1&a-e&a-e\cr a-e&1&a-e\cr a-e&a-e&1\cr}$ is PSD if $a=-1/2$ and $e=0$. If you make $e$ any tiny bit bigger than zero, the resulting matrix is no longer PSD. Is that the sort of thing you have in mind?

Is it, @Goeman?

Yes, this is helpful. Thank you!

As an example of the sort of thing OP has in mind, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&.5-e&.5-e\cr.5-e&1&.5-e\cr.5-e&.5-e&1\cr}
$$
is PSD if $e=0$, but no longer PSD for arbitrarily small $e>0$.
